# Programmatically turn on/off panels with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, panel

In QGIS, with `right-click` somewhere in the toolbar area panels can be toggled on/off like shown in the screenshot below (the GPS Information Panel for instance).

[image]

I need to do this programmatically, so how to toggle on/off panels from PyQGIS? I found that the `QgsInterface` class has some `addDockWidget` and `removeDockWidget` method, but I really couldn't figure out if this is the right way to achieve this ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those panels are [QDockWidgets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html), we can search for their `objectNames` and if it matches, set their visibility to `False` (i.e. hide them).

So for the *GPS Information Panel*, you could use:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDockWidget
for x in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QDockWidget):
    #print x.objectName()
    if x.objectName() == 'GPSInformation':
        x.setVisible(False)
```